# jquery for bootstrap modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I try to accomplish that a function is called when one of several modals on my web page is shown like this:

```
$('.modal')
.on('shown.bs.modal',
function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

But the function is never called.

It worked like this:

```
$(window)
.on('shown.bs.modal',
function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

But with this way I cannot get the element's id.

How do I accomplish it that I define one function that is called when one of several modals is shown and the right element of the modal is transfered as a parameter so I can determine the id of the modal element?

UPDATE:
I think I found the cause of my problem. I try to run this jQuery code within my angularjs controller.

UPDATE2:
I tried to run following code in my angular controller, but it is never called:

```
  $document.ready(function () {
            jQuery('.modal')
            .on('shown.bs.modal',
                function (e) {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    NgMap.getMap("map-" + id)
                        .then(function (map) {
                            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                        });
                });
        });
```

Comment: Can you give a working plunker for this issue.? When i m  trying to generate the issue, i m not able to. Also, can you show your `HTML` code?

Comment: I create the modals in my html code with a ng-repeat. I will make an example

Comment: The code you provide should work, please give more information if you haven't figured out the solution yet

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Id of modal instead class

```
$('#modal-ID') .on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) { var id = $(this).attr('id'); });
```

Comment: User is trying to find the `id` of the modal using this function. If he/she already knows the `id` why would he/she use this `function`?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to specify a different class other and then fire an event on it

like

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageUpload2">Launch modal</button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageUpload1">Launch modal</button>
<div class="sample modal fade" id="imageUpload2" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            Upload form here
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<div class="sample modal fade" id="imageUpload1" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            Upload form here
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){

     $('.sample').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
       alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EcnC3/309/)**